# Setting up two horizontal divs in Bootstrap, with only 1 going full width in mobile mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding some custom HTML to Opencart. I need a unordered list of our terms, privacy policy etc on one side in a div and then a "newsletter sign up" image on the other side in a div.

I have the "newsletter sign up" set to responsive image but it doesn't look right when in mobile so i'd rather it wasn't there and just have the terms span across the container.

How can I create 2 divs (50% of page each), that then make the left div go full width in mobile (xs)

Comment: you are using bootstrap I am guessing? Have you got a link where I could see what is your problem? Ideally a JSfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to hiding the image on mobile, the left column div must also have the correct class to expand to full width on xs screens.  Assuming you're using bootstrap for the layout, you'd want something like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
    *terms content*
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
    <img src="XYZ" />
 </div>
```

This will give you two columns that are each 50% width on screens smaller and up.  The left column will span 12 columns on xs screens, and the right column will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, all you need to do is add the class "hidden-xs" to your second div you want to disappear on mobile. You could use "hidden-sm" to hide the div at a higher viewport width. Because I can't see your code, I can't be sure but essentially:

```
<div class="hidden-xs"></div>
```

Also, you'll likely need "col-sm-6" or something like that on each div to utilize the grid system better on BS (if you don't have it already).

Comment: Its making the left div (expand) to full width from half width that I am looking for

Comment: If you have BS utilized correctly, it should automatically go full width ... would be much easier to help if code was available to review.